# Would switching to this network setup help balance the load on my main router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, switch

I currently am set up like this: 
[image]

My routers my second and third router are connected to the main via Static IPs outside the main router's DHCP range. Routers 2 and 3 have DHCP disabled (so the main router handles all DHCP). All 3 routers are on separate wifi channels. But my main router/modem keeps crashing. Even when it is working, there still is some traffic jams on the network. So I am thinking about doing something like this: 
[image]

I would basically just be throwing in a gigabit switch and moving my web server. Would this help balance the load, optimize my network, and keep my router from crashing? Im open to other suggestions too.

Comment: I think the main issue here is the crashing? If I were you I would find the issue of the crash. Maybe the routers port mappings table get overflowed, too many connections in total (active+inactive) or the router isn't able to handle that much connections at once (active connections).

Comment: The main issue is the router crashing, but the other issue is the bogged down speeds

Comment: the only "fix" I see here is to get a better main router, not just a "1gbps" router, but one which also has good performance and high load processing ability. I would suggest business class routers. You could also set up a computer to connect to the WAN with a WAN interface card, and connect a switch to the ethernet of the PC, install NAT software on the PC and you'll be ready to go, pc's are much more powerful than routers. If you are using ADSL, I suggest a PCI ADSL Modem card for your main desktop which would act as a router.

Comment: You can use your "web server" as that PC, it's on 24/7 anyway

Comment: [here](http://i.imgur.com/grF3lTq.png) is an image of what I have in mind.

Comment: The main thing to remember is that reconfiguring your LAN, does not change the fact that all internet traffic has go through your main modem/router.  So, unless you can decrease the amount of internet traffic you'll probably need to get a more powerful/stable main router.

Comment: @Gizmo You should change that comment to an answer, because I modified the Q. That seems like a good way to go. I have comcast so no ADSL. Would an old pentium 4 2.4ghz with 2gb of ram work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a computer as a router - any computer - will be much better than your current solution.

Here is an example image:

[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1ltL.png)

you can substitute the 'ADSL' word with any connection type you have, if you have cable, buy a cable modem PCI card for the computer. an intel pentium 2.4 Ghz with 2 GB ram should be more than enough.

or aquire a business class router for high loads as your main router.

Comment: is the cable modem pci card necessary? Or can I just use my modem/router as the modem (it can be configured to be just a modem) and then the desktop as the router?

Comment: that is possible to do but make sure the pc which will act as a router will have two ethernet ports - one connected to the main router and the other port acting as NAT (do NOT bridge the interfaces directly)